# How could I modify component state from parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I am starting with react and I am trying to create a really simple TODO app that will allow the user to:

- Toggle the completion status, on each TODO, individually.
- Toggle all the TODOs at the same time.

It works from the child itself, but apparently the parent state is not "in sync" with the child state.

Here is my code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/simplest-todo-app-posible-boyxe

I was not able to find a way to solve this, and looks like a quite classic scenario, but my apologies if this was asked before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, @Alberto you can lift the state up to the Parent component to be in sync. Check this doc https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I will definitely try this approach, thanks for the suggestions @YashJoshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Item` a stateless component and handle all changes from the parent.

From the parent component pass `toggleComplete` as a `prop` to `Item` to toggle `complete`

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplest-todo-app-posible-dfmh4)

```
const mockData = [{ id: 1, complete: false }, { id: 2, complete: true }];

const Item = ({ id, complete, toggleComplete }) => (
  <li>
    Task {id} is {complete ? "completed" : "not completed"}
    <button onClick={toggleComplete}>Toggle</button>
  </li>
);

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(mockData);

  const markAllAsComplete = () => {
    const newData = data.map(item => {
      console.log(`Item ${item.id} is ${item.complete}`);
      item.complete = true;
      return item;
    });

    setData(newData);
  };

  const toggleAll = () => {
    const newData = data.map(item => {
      item.complete = !item.complete;
      return item;
    });

    setData(newData);
  };

  // added this
  const toggleComplete = id => () => {
    setData(prevData =>
      prevData.map(d => (d.id === id ? { ...d, complete: !d.complete } : d))
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggleAll}>Toggle all</button>
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            complete={item.complete}
            toggleComplete={toggleComplete(item.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <ul>
        {data.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            Task id: {item.id} is
            {item.complete ? " completed" : " not completed"}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought but I was not able to pass the TODO id to the parent. Many thanks for your solution!